# Getchar() analog in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to read only 1 char (number, to be exact) from cmd.exe. It must be done in only one keystroke. Is that possible? Not only cmd.exe, but I mean all standard utilities in windows (supported by WinXP-Win7).

PS `set /p val=request` **is not what I looking for**. It reads string, not only 1 char and require <kbd>enter</kbd> key. I need something what works like `OnKeyDown`: read 1 char and continue script execution, no <kbd>enter</kbd> needed.

Comment: I'm not positive how to answer this. Perhaps some more explaination on why you need this will help?

Comment: Are you reading from the *keyboard* or from *another program's output*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not only `cmd.exe`, but I mean all standard utilities in windows (supported by WinXP-Win7).

Why would it need to be possible for, say, `edlin.exe`?  That's a nonsensical requirement.

If you want to prompt for a single character, returning immediately once one is entered, then you are going to have to use *some* form of extra utility over and above what comes in the box with Windows NT 5.1, even if it's simply a Win32 clone of the MS-DOS 6.2 `choice.com` program (which, being an MS-DOS program, won't work on x86-64 Windows, of course).

With [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html), which is a replacement command interpreter, the built-in [`INKEY` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/inkey.htm) does exactly what you ask for and can be used thusly:

```
inkey %%key
```

The key pressed is then in the `key` environment variable.

Alternatively, [in the Windows NT 4.0 Server Resource Kit](http://microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windowsnt/4/server/reskit/en-us/reskt4u4/rku4list.mspx) and later, Microsoft provides `choice.exe`, which is a Win32 clone of the MS-DOS `choice.com`.  Note, however, that this is the *Server* Resource Kit.  With Windows NT Server 5.2 and later, `choice.exe` is [bundled in with Windows itself](http://www.microsoft.com/hun/windowsserver2003/overview3.mspx).  However, again, note that this is the *Server* edition of Windows.

Comment: I found choice.exe in my Win7x64: C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-choice_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_c33d412fed16819c It works great.

Comment: choice is located in C:\Windows\System32\choice.exe in 64-bit Windows